# Tailwind classes not applying

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css, web-frontend, tailwind-3

Tailwind background and height class not working in my code, really don't why it's happening I've double-checked all the things but have no clue what's going on.

```
import React from "react";
import Logo from "../assets/footer-background-logo.svg";
export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center bg-[#00ade9] h-80 relative">
      <img src={Logo} className="absolute top-80 w-32 h-32" alt="logo"></img>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the codesandbox reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/footer-image-4sivbt?file=/src/components/Homepage.js:0-296

Comment: You have Tailwind 1.0.4 installed on this Code Sandbox link, neither the h-80 or the arbitrary values will work with this version of Tailwind.

Comment: ooh, can you please guide how to upgrade this?

Comment: Tailwind has an official upgrade guide https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide